# Servelts, jsp error return true

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, login, validación

Estoy haciendo un mantenedor de datos en jsp, asi que para la parte de la validación de usuarios use servelts para hacer las llamadas a mysql.

En el servelts de consultas.java tengo esto(es para hacer reedireccion 1 es admin 2 es estandar):

```
    public boolean comprobar (String usuario,String contraseña){
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs =null;
    try {
        String sql = "Select nivel from usuarios where usuario = ? and password =?";
        pst = getconexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, usuario);
        pst.setString(2, contraseña);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("nivel");
            System.out.print(id);
            if (id == 1) {
               return true; 
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error comprobar"+e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Luego en el servelt de login.java tengo uno para validar el usuario existente el cual hace lo mismo devuelve true o false, y dentro introdusco la comprobacion del nivel de usuario

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String usuario = request.getParameter("txt_user");
    String contraseña = request.getParameter("txt_pass");

    consultas co = new consultas();

    if (co.autenticacion(usuario, contraseña)) {//Este da true sin dramas

        if (co.comprobar(usuario, contraseña)) {//Este deberia dar true desde consultas.java
            response.sendRedirect("entrada_admin.jsp");

        }else{ //Pero siempre termina aca sin importar el usuario  -__-
            response.sendRedirect("entrada_estandar.jsp");
        }

    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
}
```

Como sale comentado, el codigo no me envia donde yo deseo. He probado el comprobar con este codigo dentro de consultas y devuelve true y false sin problemas.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    consultas co = new consultas();
    System.out.println(co.comprobar("usuario", "contraseña"));

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Qué significa "no me envía donde yo deseo" exactamente? ¿Te envía siempre a uno de los dos, o pasa otra cosa? Además, deberías poner al menos un log para comprobar qué rama se está ejecutando; podría ser muy bien que tuvieras el problema en los parámetros o en otra parte.

Comment: Osea para ser mas preciso, tengo un usuario que solo debe entrar a "entradada_admin.jsp"(1, el cual significa que co.comprobar dio == true) y otro que por defecto (2, false) solo debería ir a "entrada_estandar.jsp". Pero al ejecutar el sitio sin importar el nivel de usuario (si es 1 o 2) me lleva al Else e ingresa a "entrada_estandar.jsp". Quiero que cuando de true entre a uno y false al otro

Answer (score 0):

el detalle es que si tu mismo estas diciendo que es true o false el problema no esta en el metodo o funcion que estas realizando si no en la vista que estas retornando deberias dar mas informacion de que es lo que estas usando para mostrar plantillas thymeleaf , Struts2 , etc..